# Predicting financial transactions

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I would like to build software to help folks with their personal finances. One area I would like to tackle is trying to predict future transactions based in past transactions. For instance you might see the electric bill being paid near a certain day of the month. The algorithm would then be able to create future predicted transactions in a forecast that would show that bill being paid on that day. It would do that for all the bills and be able to lay out a cash flow forecast based on it.

By cash flow I mean a listing of transactions that are expected to occur in the future based on past patterns. So as in my example, any bills found to pay with certain patterns would continue to follow that pattern.

I think machine learning (ML) is the right tool. I've done a lot of learning in the area but have yet to see something that seems to fit this kind of problem. Any ideas as to what algorithms would be applied? I'm just looking for some nudges in the right direction as to which ML algorithms would be best to look into.

I'll back up and try to give more context to the problem. So today if you want to get the benefit of any kind of forecasting tool for your personal finances, you generally are manually entering and then maintaining a list of bills. I would like to eliminate this need. If you look at a checking account, it probably would be evident to you that certain bills pay on certain schedules, even if you weren't familiar with the account. So pattern recognition that humans currently would do fairly easily in simpler cases. Sounds classically ML to me. So I would like to try to apply that. The end desired result from this is a projected cash flow showing what the future checking account might look like if the current trends continued.

Please note that the sentiment of not using ML at all is well understood. I disagree and I'm looking for help with the ML. General lectures about the nature of ML and other suggestions about simple averages do not address the question at all.

Comment: The solution to the specific problem you described is simply a *moving average.*

Comment: Machine learning is way overthinking this.

Comment: @whatsisname I've considered going a more traditional approach and I may still do that. However it's really a pattern recognition problem. I want something that can spot statistical patterns in the data. I think ML would be the most robust approach to this. We use ML in my current work and it operates as a simple to use black box. It's ok for me to spend some time thinking about this and picking out the right tool if I can solve it better than it has been so far.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks. I've tried looking into that but so far nothing seems to hit the nail for what I need. If you have some references or more info that would be great.

Comment: Then you need to make your question more specific.  So far, all you have in your question is that you need some predictive capabilities that are finance-based.  That's not enough to go on.  I think that if you take the time to make your problem more specific, you will find that you don't need machine learning at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I read it back and it's pretty clearly spelled out. If you could tell me what's confusing you I'll spell it out more clearly. If you don't think ML is the right solution then your comments are off topic for the post. It's a statistical pattern recognition problem. It's pretty classically an ML problem to me. At any rate I want to explore the options in that space hence my post. If I choose not to go this route I'll put out another post with that as the topic.

Comment: But you haven't provided enough detail for anyone else to identify the specific pattern recognition problem you are having.  I know it seems crystal clear to you from your perspective, but you have the advantage of knowing the problem in its entirety.  See also [What is the X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/102937).

Comment: I tried adding some more detail. You aren't being specific either in what is confusing you. I'll add more that I can think of that would clarify.

Comment: What does "projected cash flow" mean?  Are you trying to prevent overdrafts? Every ML requires a goal; what is the actual goal that an ML would be moving towards?

Comment: I explained that. A listing of future predicted transactions based on the prior patterns. That is the actual goal. It's useful for a human being to see this to better comprehend their own finances. It could help with overdrafts sure. It could help with deciding what to put in savings. It helps to see if you suddenly started paying a bill that is putting you on a negative trajectory. There are lots of potential use cases but the thrust of my question was to get help from those who had some ML expertise so I could investigate that potential.

Comment: Perhaps this was the wrong forum for it. I did post this on the machine learning subreddit. The first response told me to google it and learn for myself. After that some folks actually tried to help and gave some ideas. What a mind blowing concept. I posted here after the first nasty comment on Reddit hoping to get some actual feedback from fellow programmers. Instead I'm getting a general attack against ML.

Comment: It's not uncommon for folks new to Programmers to mistake it as "just another discussion forum."  Stack Exchange is a "Question and Answer" system; it is based on specific answers to specific questions.  I apologize if you were expecting a discussion.

Comment: I was expecting help with my question. You can't provide it so you're deflecting.

Comment: It's funny the amount of closed as not constructive questions are on SO, are very high level and opinion driven, and yet still have very high listings in google and lots of upvotes. Then you come along with your "not a discussion forum" claim. Just not in line with reality.

Answer (score 2):

The overarching principle behind machine learning is that it consumes a data set composed of inputs and historical outputs, updates its internal state, and, when given a new and novel set of inputs, can guess an output that falls into the historical pattern as demonstrated in the historical data.  In order for the machine to determine whether an output is valid, it needs feedback-- e.g. you run the machine on historical inputs and see if it can compute historical outputs.

If the computed output differs from the actual output, the difference is called a cost function... the machine would then update its internal state variables (typically some sort of weights or biases) to minimize cost with repeated exposure to more data.

In a typical experimental design, the inputs and outputs used for learning come from a different data set from the inputs and outputs used to test validity.  E.g. if you expose a machine to John's inputs and outputs, see if it can learn enough to compute Bob's outputs if given Bob's inputs.  So you are going to need a lot of data!

Ask yourself what are the inputs and outputs and what exactly you want your "machine" to be able to compute.

For example

Inputs: An array of financial transactions, for a certain period of interest.  Each item in the array is composed of the following attributes: date, amount, and type.

Output: Total cash flow for the period of interest.

The above can be accomplished via simple math, e.g. add up the *amount* field from all of the inputs-- the result is the output.

That is it.

Now, if you insist on overthinking this, I suppose you could go to a great deal of trouble to train a neural network to figure out the right gradient values to be able to perform addition without explicitly telling it that it has to do addition (this is not trivial!)  OR you could simply code the machine to perform addition,  because you know that is what has to be done.  In which case **you don't need machine learning at all**.

I'm guessing that the problem you are trying to solve does not need machine learning-- rather, what you need is a static model, which you yourself would design rather than the machine.

A simple moving average might work.  If you want to go a little crazy you could arrange your data in a [general linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model) which could predict values quite nicely, assuming that the overall mechanism is not nonlinear.  So far in your question you have not demonstrated the need for anything more sophisticated than that.

Comment: I simply don't know how much more clearly I can explain this. I want to project transactions based on past patterns. I don't just want to project averages. I could devise a complex program to look for those patterns or I could use the tools of ML to look for those patterns. Nothing in your post addresses the need in the slightest. It wouldn't figure out that I tend to pay groceries every week lets say and I tend to pay my rent once a month or any other patterns. Yes I could just run monthly averages. However that is NOT the topic of this post. That is NOT what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Perhaps start by listing, *precisely*, the inputs and outputs that your machine will process.

Comment: I have. The inputs are transactions like you would see in your bank account. Date description and amount. The output would be a forecast of those transactions if the general trends continued. That is all in my original post. Rather than helping, folks are attacking my premise. If you don't like the premise then why are you wasting my time and your time in responding to a question based on it. It's like asking questions about C# and getting answers about how I shouldn't use C#. I have a pattern recognition problem

Comment: That I want to solve. ML could be a good tool. The question is what ML tool is best. If you don't have an answer to that question fine. But stop answering questions I didn't ask.

Comment: See [this](http://www.behavior-change.net/covey-5-seek-first-to-understand-then-to-be-understood/) then read [this](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Solution_in_search_of_a_problem).  A general linear model would perform the prediction you are requesting.  If you have some notion that the problem is nonlinear, you will need to account for more inputs, e.g. if you think there is a seasonality aspect to it then season would be an input-- a machine sitting on a table without exposure to the real world will not know this notion until you tell it about it.

Comment: Thank you. That was actually constructive. I agree I should feed seasons and holidays into it. But so far I don't know how to even structure an algorithm to care. I would feed day of week and day of month as well. But even still it should find patterns that are say biweekly. That's what makes it an ML application to me. I want to find patterns that as a human you would find if you studied it. Cars drive for themselves now for goodness sake. The same tools can't find patterns in bill pay? Maybe I'm wrong. I clearly overshot by asking here. I'll work on it alone.

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://dilbert.com/strip/2002-10-14)